# Add dictionary values together when duplicated

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, io

I think I'm on the right track but have something wrong here:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

merged = {}

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    dictReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    dictReader.fieldnames = "Part", "Qty"
    headlessDict = islice(dictReader, 2, None)
    for row in headlessDict:
        print(row['Part'].split(',')[0], row['Qty'])
    # for d in headlessDict:
    #     for k, v in d.items():
    #         if k not in merged:
    #             merged[k] = []
    #         merged[k].append(v)
```

I'm opening a csv file and then assigning new headers (part & qty) to them.  I'm then using the islice module to skip over the first two lines as I don't need them, and finally iterating through and printing the results which look like this (after cutting off some extra detail in the first column with the split):

```
A434343 19
B983943 22
DK8383E39 37
...
```

What I'm trying to then accomplish is to say, "Hey, if there are duplicates in the result set (i.e. There could be two or more of A434343 but with different quantities listed) I ultimately want to take the quantities and add them together and create a new dictionary with the cleaned up list.

I'm stuck now and could use some help.  Please advise oh masterful ones!

Comment: Write the pseudo code: If key isn't in dict ... else ...

Comment: I did that and that's how I started with the commented out code but I got stuck. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to append the values well enough.  Can you simply add them instead?  That commented-out code can look like this:

```
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k not in merged:
                merged[k] = 0
            merged[k] += int(v)
```